# Storyboard, where to drag connection from one view controller to the next

Tags: iphone, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I'm confused on how storyboarding works.

So I created a simple app where the root view controller is a navigation controller.
I dragged a button to the the rootViewController of the NavigationController.
I dragged another view controller onto the screen, made it's background orange, and made it a subclass of OrangeViewController.
I dragged a connection from the status bar area of my rootViewController to the OrangeViewController.
I made this Segue Push and called it ShowOrange.
I created an action for my button that has:

```
- (IBAction)push:(id)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowOrange" sender:self];
}
```

That's all it does.  So when I press the button, it does show OrangeViewController.  Then when I press back however, it keeps my background Orange.  The title does change to ViewController, and there is no back button, but the background is orange.  I was wondering why it does this?

My other question is a generic question with dragging segues.  I seem to be able to drag it from the button itself, or the status bar.  Is there a difference?  What is really happening when that connection is made?  Thanks.

Edit: Picture included
[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: @ctrahey I added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

This particular answer is just for your second question:

Dragging from the button is analogous to setting that button's action to be performing the segue. Dragging from the view controller object (which is what I think is happening when you drag from the 'status bar', and would also happen if you dragged from the view controller while more zoomed out, or from the view controller in the list view), you are just setting it up to be used in code (in this case, it *must* have an identifier. The button segue does not need an identifier).